# For loop data frame error when working with character vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, character

I am currently doing data science with R and I generally write loops to access multiple files or objects at once. Normally this goes without any problems but recently a problem occurred when trying to run the following code:

```
setwd(PROJECT_FOLDER)

climate_forcing <- c("cf-1", "cf-2", "cf-3", "cf-4")

#load all mean stacks from IM and create rasterstack
for (i in 1:NROW(climate_forcing)){
  setwd(PROJECT_FOLDER)
  setwd(paste0("time frames mcor/X variable/IM/", climate_forcing[i], "/ncstack/"))
  file.names <- list.files(pattern = ".nc", recursive=T, full.names=F)                #list all files with ".nc"
  stopwords <- c(".nc", "stack", "/dLAI")                                             #stopwords
  names.short <- gsub(paste(stopwords, collapse="|"), "", file.names)       
  assign("names.short", paste0(names.short, climate_forcing[i]))
  for (j in 1:NROW(file.names)){                                                     
    assign(paste0(names.short[j], "_stack"), stack(file.names[j]))
  } 
}
```

Error message returned:

```
Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

I wrote this a while ago and I ran it before and I think it used to work since the files being created by a similar script are there.
Anyways I did some testing and it seems that the **error occurs in the for loop within the for loop (with the variable j)**. I am unsure what may cause this bug but has to do something with "file.names" and "names.short" right? When I compare them, their properties appear to be identical though, which I figured would be, since I create the latter out of the former. The reason I am creating them like this is because I want to create objects reading out the corresponding files of file.names.
The error I get refers to data.frame which confuses me because I'm working with character vectors here..

Maybe somebody with more experience can figure this issue out.
Thanks for any help and if there are any questions I will try to answer them.

Comment: Maybe some temp file created around your directories!

Comment: @Duck I believe not (wouldn't know how). The files in the folders are the ones of interest.

Comment: Nothing in the code should relate to `data.frame`, except `stack(file.names[j])`. Could it be that something is wrong with one of your .nc files? I would check the value of `j` after it gives error. Did the for loop run at all?

Comment: Yes that should be it (unfortunately).. The loop didn't run and when I try to access the files one by one there's always this error. Quite upsetting.. I think need to fix and run many scripts (that create those nc files) again now.. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright it turns out something was wrong with the R packages, I reinstalled and reloaded them (raster) and now it works. Thanks to anyone for your contributions!